# How to invoke SOAP client from localhost by NuSOAP?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I am a new-b for PHP-SOAP environment and for ease I am using NuSOAP library to invoke a secured SOAP service, I am using localhost and XAMPP v3.2.2. Can you tell me what are the values I must put for the proxies?

```
$proxyhost = 
$proxyport = 
$proxyusername = 'user1';
$proxypassword = 'password';
```

I am using the above variable to create the proxies and then use the

```
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true, $proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);
```

to call create the client but no idea what to put for proxyhost, proxyport and I got the WSDL link from the API and that also i stored inside the $wsdl. I tried to read the docs and the samples by the NuSOAP but they are not much helping me to understand.

Following is an extract from the API document,

> 3. Security: All web services API(s) requires WS-Security enabled. A sample WS security header is as follows.

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" S:mustUnderstand="1">

     <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurityutility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-1459705815762-1589144727">

        <wsse:Username>user1</wsse:Username>

        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>

        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-messagesecurity-1.0#Base64Binary">q+c/hlLx/cOiXXbYbWc4KauB</wsse:Nonce>

        <wsu:Created>2016-04-03T17:50:15.857Z</wsu:Created>

     </wsse:UsernameToken>

</wsse:Security>
```

Please do help e understanding above XML keywords as well, why is that OASIS link for, what is UsernameToken.

Thanks in advance.